# can not receive UDP packet?

Tags: c, udp

I am calling setup_udp_socket method from main which setup a UDP socket on  udppport and then I use select on this socket. When  I have something to read on this method I call udp_communication () but I receive strange output

[There is no message received i.e. 0 bytes but strlen of char array gives  1 ]. the UDP packet is send by another Java program to which I do not have access. I used nc and tested it worked fine. but there seems to be some problem in my code which i am not able to figure out.

I am waiting

listener: got packet from 127.0.0.1 and port number :48555

Message received: number of bytes : 0 len: 1

Exiting udp_communication

```
int setup_udp_socket(char* udpport)
{
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        int ret_value;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        if ((ret_value = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", udpport, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret_value));
                exit(FAILED);
        }

        for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
                if ((udp_sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                                     p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
                        perror("udp: socket creation failed");
                        continue;
                }

                if (bind(udp_sock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                        close(udp_sock);
                        perror("udp: bind");
                        continue;
                }
                //listen(udp_sock, 20);

                break;
        }

        if (p == NULL) {
                if (servinfo != NULL)
                    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
                exit(FAILED);
        }

        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
        printf("udp: waiting to recvfrom and udpport :%s\n", udpport);

}
```

//udp_recvbuf is char array of 1024 bytes.

```
void udp_communication() {

        struct sockaddr_storage addr;
        socklen_t addr_len;
        char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        int n;
        addr_len = sizeof(addr);
        //udp_sock_flag = fcntl(udp_sock, F_GETFL, 0);
        //fcntl(udp_sock, F_SETFL, udp_sock_flag | O_NONBLOCK);


//       while(1) {

        memset(udp_recvbuf, '\0', BUFFERSIZE);
        printf("I am waiting\n");
        if (n = recvfrom(udp_sock, udp_recvbuf, 1023 , 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_len) == -1) {
                perror("recvfrom");
                exit(1);
        }
         printf("listener: got packet from %s and port number :%d\n ",
        inet_ntop(addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&addr),
            s, sizeof s), ((struct sockaddr_in *)&addr)->sin_port);
          printf("Message received:%s number of bytes : %d len: %d\n", udp_recvbuf, n, strlen(udp_recvbuf));

//      } 


        printf("Exiting udp_communication\n");

        //pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: In your implementation, you may need to check the `errno` when `n` is equal to `-1` i.e. output of `recvfrom` is `-1`. Your code may have to continue to wait if the socket was non-blocking. Have you tried this?

Comment: yes actually if you scroll the code to right you will be able to see it.
also its a blocking call right. the flag = 0

Comment: ok.. What i meant was when `n` is `-1`, the error code may be `EAGAIN` which means that you may have to loop over and perform another `recvfrom`

Comment: but the value of n I get is 0.
also i tried putting it in a while loop to do multiple recvfrom but no luck.

Comment: If you are getting `n` as zero, then it means that there are no messages to be received and the remote peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

Comment: My parentheses were incorrect. Now i get the value of n as 7 which is expected.

Comment: don't call strlen on binary data.  It's a bad thing(tm)